# Is it possible to load a local file without having to ask the user to browse to it first in an AIR Application?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'm writing a small application for myself and instead of using a database I'd like to just use Excel to store the small amount of data I have on my local file system. I want to be able to load that data without having to use the typical `FileReference browse()` method as it would just be annoying to do every time I use the application.

The code below seems to find the file fine as the file.exists method below and most of the other attributes seem to be correct but the `file.data` is always null.

I'm guessing this is a security issue and that's why I'm running into this problem but I thought I'd ask and see if there is in fact a way around this problem.

```
var file:File = new File(fullPath + "\\" + currentFolder + ".txt");
if(file.exists) {
     var byteArray:ByteArray = file.data;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read the content of a file, use the following code:

```
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open("some path here", FileMode.READ);
var fileData:String = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);
trace(fileData);
```

The data property is inherited from FileReference class and it will be populated only after a load call (see this [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#data)).

Comment: Good to know it is possible. I should have put it in the original question, I assumed it would be similar for all file types but what if the file is an excel file. I tried both your approach and Tyler's and it doesn't seem to properly get the data. Both implementations just get a tab(\t) returned or just gibberish looking characters.

Comment: If you are reading binary data you cannot use readUTFBytes but readBytes. If you are reading text data with some specific encoding (other than utf) use readMultiByte method

Answer (score 3):

You're close, you just need to combine that with a FileStream object

```
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
var str:String = fileStream.readMultiByte(file.size, File.systemCharset);
trace(str);
```

[more info here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#open%28%29)