# Kiosk game writing local files AS3 without AIR? Possible? If not, local server?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xampp

I am setting up a kiosk game that will be taken on the road.  I need to be able to write XML files to the local hard disk (no internet connection guaranteed).

I realize that AIR is the way to go, but for various reasons — one of which is that the client prefers this not run as AIR, as it's going to be inside the YCD media player and it's easier for the client to work with SWFs -- I'd like to explore non-AIR options.

Is there any way to write to local files without a prompt?  I take it from prior discussions ([Is it possible to load a local file without having to ask the user to browse to it first in an AIR Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786236/is-it-possible-to-load-a-local-file-without-having-to-ask-the-user-to-browse-to)) the answer is 'no'.  True?

If I had internet access I could write to a server and do a little PHP to write to a file.  How hard would this be to setup on a Windows machine and do locally?  I know absolutely nothing about Windows and don't have a Windows machine to work on so I'd like to make it simple.  And this would need to work flawlessly on the backroads and be maintainable by non-tech-savvy persons.  Someone suggested XAMMP…

Ideally, of course, if I could come up with a AS3-only solution that would be great.  Or perhaps (if someone knows it) something to work with the YCD player…

Thanks!

Comment: make it talk to a server set up on localhost to do the writing.

Comment: For very very good reason you cannot write files without the local prompt. If your client doesn't like air, what you can do is export AIR projects with captive runtime so you just get a standard .exe file that doesn't need AIR installed.   A similar solution is MDM Zinc

Comment: If you have to just use swfs, what you can do is use `SharedObjects`.  Check out my example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667848/as3-for-ios-how-to-serialize-an-array-and-then-save-it/15668079#15668079  .   SharedObjects are just cookies though and you'd have to make sure they don't get cleared if you want the data to be long-term persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing only with small data, `SharedObjects` can solve your problem just as LondonDrugs_MediaServices said in his comment. You can write anything to those, but its limited to 100KB by default. To get more you must accept a [prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5mKG.jpg) or [preset](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html) it to a bigger size.

> Is there any way to write to local files without a prompt?

`SharedObjects` aside, you cannot do that for security reasons. If you are using only the flash player, web or projector, you cannot **write** files directly without a prompt. You can **read** local files from both but you must know your [sandbox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6167e-7fff.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6167e-7ff9) as it gets messy when you mix network and local file access.

If you can run a local webserver I suggest you use [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) because it is small,has PHP, is simple to setup and can run on mostly anything. Beware that you still have to mind your [security sandbox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html), but serving your SWF from the same local webserver simplifies that.

Comment: Thanks — it's XML data.  I decided to simply have them run a simple server setup (XAMMP) and write using a simple PHP script.